# Android - Google signin issue with Oauth2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-keystore

I encounter an error when implementing google signin on my application.

During the test of my application, after selecting a google account I get this error:

W/SignInActivity: signInResult:failed code=10

After some research I tried to add the Oauth2 client id.

I generated it via the google console by indicating the name of the package present in the manifest. And I retrieved the SHA1 code using "signinReport" from android studion. (I got the debug key because I use the build debug variant).

Then I put it there:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .requestIdToken("MY_TOKEN")
    .build();
```

I also read several topics about the google-services.json file. But I can't find it on google console. Does it still exist?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this 2 blogs solved your problem, pls read this

[Goole auth](https://codingmitra.com/oauth-getting-started-in-google-login)

[Google Login](https://codingmitra.com/integration-google-login-in-android)

This one is help for you

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I got the files from the tutorial to make sure I had the correct code.
Then I created my Oauth android client id using as package name "lifs.loginwithgoogle" and then as fingerprint the value recovered via "signinreport" on my project. (I followed the google auth tutorial for android)

Then I put my client id in the variable "client_id" of the file "strings.xml".

But then when I try to connect I always get error 10: "E/TAG: REsult :10".

So I don't understand what's blocking there...

Comment: please string.xml add web client id , then it will worked

Comment: also required to create web client id, i mentioned on tutorial

Comment: yesterday , i checked code, so please also create web client

Comment: Hum... It works with the web client id O_o. Thank you very much^^.
 But why did we have to use the web id client and not android?